# Excel Solver Curve Fitting Failing - MatLab recast

Tags: excel, matlab, curve-fitting, solver

I am having some strange problems with excel's solver. Basically what I am trying to do is curve fit my data. I have two different lines, one is my calibration line and the other is the derived line that I am attempting to match up to the calibration line. My line depends on 19 different variable parameters (Perhaps this is too many? I have tried fewer without result) and I am using solver to adjust these parameters to make the two lines as close as possible.

For Example:

The QP column contains the variables I would like changed, changing these will draw me closer or further from the calibration curve. Each subsequent value of QP must be greater than the first.

```
Col=B   Col=C

Power  .QP_'

1   .....    57000  
2    .....   65000  
3   .....    70000   
4   .....    80000  
5   .....    80000
```

Therefore my excel solver parameters look like this: `C1:C19>=0,C1:C19<=100000` and `C2>=C1, C3>=C2,C4>=C3`... I have also tried making another column of the differences between each value and then saying that these must be `diff>=0`.

To compare this with my calibration curve I have taken the calibration curve data and subtracted my data derived from `QP` and then squared that to create my sum of the squares error. For example:

`(Calibration-DerivedQP)^2=SS(x)    <- where x represents the row number`

`Sum(SS(x))=SSE`

`SSE` is what I have set solver to minimize. And upon changing `QP` everything automatically updates. There are no if statements being used and no pivot tables are used.

If I remove the parameters similar to `C2>=C1` everything works perfectly, except the derived values are not feasible. But when the solver is run with these parameters, nothing gets changed and no matter which guesses I used as starting values ( so that I can ensure I haven't guessed a local minimum), the solver cannot improve upon my solution. This has led me to believe that something in my parameters is being broken, since I can very easily improve on my solution by guess and check. The rest of solvers settings are at the defaults, and the evolutionary method is used since my curve isn't smooth (I don't think) I had this working in the past and now something seems to be broken. Any ideas are appreciated! Thank you so much! Sorry if I am missing any critical information. I am also familiar with matlab and R if there are better methods in those languages.

Comment: You mean like adding a trend-line?  I have charts but fitting a general curve wont work unfortunately, also it wouldn't tell me the values of Q that I need. Unless I am missing something?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I didnt included sample data since it is fairly complex and I thought it would convolute my question. And unfortunately tracking back through the math to derive these values would not be possible especially since my polynomial would need to have several thousand terms since my data set is so varied and large. My thought was that perhaps my parameters were wrong and throwing off solver. I am certain that the calculations that are not included are correct.

Comment: A few questions. 1) How many data points are you trying to fit? 2) What is the equation of the line you try to fit? Polynomial? Bezier? Hermite polynomials? 3) What is DerivedQP? `R` and `MatLab` do have better methods, but excel is likely OK for this problem as well. To see if solver works, use a ridiculously bad starting point and see if it gets improved.

Comment: I dont think so I am only adjusting the Cells I listed above, which is about 19, these then update other cells so that shouldnt be the problem.

Comment: I guess fit isn't really the correct word, QP is a frequency and my calibration curve is just a scatter of points I know for sure not an equation unfortunately. QPDerived is just my predicted values based on QP, (there is some abstract math going on in these boxes).  Essentially I am graphing the calibration points vs the time they were collected averaged by month. My P and QP are then deriving some points that approximate these values also on a monthly average. I then graph this on the same chart. There are around 10,000 points of data in the graph but only 24 months are represented.

Comment: Solver doesnt work with a bad guess under these parameters, if I remove the parameters like C2>=C1 then it matches the curve almost exactly but with nonsensical QP values.

Comment: [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) is supposed to be a free alternative of MatLab but I have never tried it. [SciPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) is a good Python alternative if you are familiar with Python. I would move to R after considering these options. If you show us your function, we might be able to help with reformulating the problem in a format more amenable to solver.

Comment: Thanks I will look into octave and scipy!. And Loannis thank you Ill try linearizing although that seems unlikely. Also I fortunately have access to matlab, is there a specific package I need?

Comment: MatLab is cool, if there is a solution to your problem it should be there. Check the [Curve Fitting](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/curvefitting/) and [Optimization](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/optimization/?s_cid=sol_des_sub2_relprod1_optimization_toolbox) toolboxes. Retagging as `MatLab` so that it attracts more attention of that community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. I don't know if this will be helpful to anyone else since my problem vague and pretty specific to me. That being said, my problem was in the constraints. I changed some data on my excel sheet to allow for fewer constraints. An example might look like this:

Guess..........Squared......Added..................Q
 -12..............(-12)^2....... 0
 -16..............(-16)^2.......=(-16)^2+0.............256
  +7.................(7)^2..........=(7)^2+(-16)^2+0....305

Now I allow solver to guess any number subject to minimal constraints.
Essentially, what is happening now, is the excel sheet allows for any guess that solver makes to work. By squaring the numbers it give me positive values, and the added column ensures that each successive value is equal to or greater than the first. This means there are very few constraints. I also changed the solver option from evolutionary to GRG Nonlinear.

Tips for getting solver to work:
Try and use the spreadsheet to set constraints (other than bounds, bounds seem to be good) wherever possible, the more constraints that I set in solver, the less likely my solution was to work.

Hope that helps, sorry if I have provided any incorrect information.